# VirutalBox: apt download / hashing problem (APT Hash Sum Mismatch)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, hashsum

I'm trying to install docker with apt from the `https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/` repo.

Unfortunately installation always fails with a hash mismatch warning. I have already tried everything suggested in this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error without any success.

The thing is when I compare the hash of the following error

```
Fetched 21.4 MB in 17s (1,290 kB/s)                                                                                          
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/buster/pool/stable/amd64/containerd.io_1.2.13-2_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:e0432c524abf9d915d42eab87c0a6cf4bd589cf2f250652253f98099c7961196f59ea0eb3f5683b05eafd969254e614739dc5681da0573b09a2eab64ab4efcfd
    - SHA256:71209f4a958d94639cba81ba3469d0aa9eff3da484106580959f5cf1fd116666
    - SHA1:08fd3a4a4e82a1c0452c6bbd5803b19315c7e968 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:2ed3788e04a8a8787ea83b8b3a00152f [weak]
    - Filesize:21404482 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA512:24c80b4371056e0b7c34a7e9abde3ee62ecfb8ee5dbbb8db4a48104b16574749588ca00f71bc4d7c4fe148a9f706e86a9a2b4ac1f5f7955bfb316950f093de49
    - SHA256:81753f427efcc308215d8a604e020743ab86ff2c45d67d86f35291d14550e203
    - SHA1:316d0bbe37b28c9da64bfa263e2b31a3bbe7199e [weak]
    - MD5Sum:8dacbbff65f077d567ab1bff2cc2ad4b [weak]
    - Filesize:21404482 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Fri, 15 May 2020 03:23:56 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

with the output of `md5sum containerd.io_1.2.13-2_amd64.deb` (file downloaded manually from https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/buster/pool/stable/amd64/containerd.io_1.2.13-2_amd64.deb)

I get the md5 hash `2ed3788e04a8a8787ea83b8b3a00152f  containerd.io_1.2.13-2_amd64.deb` which is exactly what apt claims is the expected value.

**So my only guess is that apt is either downloading something wrong or hashes the wrong way.** This sound quite strange to me and I could not find any help searching for this.

Here is my `sources.list`

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# 

# deb cdrom:[Official Debian GNU/Linux Live 10.4.0 xfce 2020-05-09T10:59]/ buster main

# deb cdrom:[Official Debian GNU/Linux Live 10.4.0 xfce 2020-05-09T10:59]/ buster main

deb http://ftp.tu-clausthal.de/debian/ buster main
deb-src http://ftp.tu-clausthal.de/debian/ buster main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.tu-clausthal.de/debian/ buster-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.tu-clausthal.de/debian/ buster-updates main

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable
```

Debian is running in a virtual machine. Host system is Windows 10.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: If you download the file manually (it appears that the downloaded file has correct hash) and copy it to your rpm cache directory, then install it.  The `apt` should take the file from its cache.

Comment: `rpm` ist not installed on my system. Where would I find the cache directory?

Comment: found the apt cache directory under `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. Copying the deb file there and then installing works but this is a pretty dirty workaround and not a permanent fix...

Comment: Ah, sorry about the `rpm` I meant the `deb`.  Well that is not a *dirty* workaround, it is simply a workaround (you do manually what apt does anyways).  You probably have some issue with ISP's proxy.  Can you connect to some VPN and try it there?  Perpahs you could try a different source?

Comment: Sorry if that did sound rude. Unfortunately I do not have access to a VPN right now but I tried installing using a mobile hotspot with the same result. The providers for the wifi's internet and the smartphone with the hotspor are different.

Comment: It did not sound rude, but I consider a dirty hack a workflow where you are somehow bending in ugly way the current state. This is was a plain test, how things go. Could update your question with information about the repository configuration?  Do you download it via http, https, ftp, ftps?

Comment: Are you on Windows? Might be [this bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235914/hash-sum-mismatch-error-due-to-identical-sha1-and-md5-but-different-sha256/1241893#comment2092986_1241893)

Comment: @muru was too fast.  You are right about the `https` already being there....

Comment: @muru Yes and indeed the last anwser of that post solved the problem (disable hyper-V) !

Comment: @muru add your answer so the question can be closed as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @muru for referring to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235914/hash-sum-mismatch-error-due-to-identical-sha1-and-md5-but-different-sha256/1241893#comment2092986_1241893), it was indeed a problem with Windows' hyper-v and VirtualBox. Disabling the hyper-v acceleration solved the problem.